# String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to execute the following SQL query using MS SQL Server Management Studio express.

```
 Insert INTO SU_PRO_RE ( d_id, fis_year, last_dp, budget_amt)  VALUES ( 'A','2011', 0, 205000.00);
```

Everything looks correct to me but every time i try to execute it it has the following:

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

The tables as set as follows:

```
d_id        = char(1) *PK*
fis_year    = char(2) *PK*
last_dp     = smallint
budget_amt  = money
```

I'm not sure what i am doing incorrect but i'm sure i am just over looking something very obvious so any help would be great! :)

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fis_year` is defined as `char(2)` but you're trying to insert a 4 character value of '2011'.

Comment: @Lamak: Great minds think alike. Not sure how that explains my mind though. :-)

Comment: Yep that was it, Joe. I knew it had to be something small like that. Guess i was just over-thinking it too much. :o) Thanks!

Comment: well, thanks for the compliment....i'm not sure if anything can explain your mind ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the field `fis_year` is defined as `CHAR(2)`, and you are trying to insert a value that has 4 charachters long.

Comment: Thanks for your reply as well, Lamak! :o)